# Python 3 smtplib send with unicode characters

Tags: python, email, unicode, python-3.x, smtplib

I'm having a problem emailing unicode characters using smtplib in Python 3.  This fails in 3.1.1, but works in 2.5.4:

```
  import smtplib
  from email.mime.text import MIMEText

  sender = to = 'ABC@DEF.com'
  server = 'smtp.DEF.com'
  msg = MIMEText('€10')
  msg['Subject'] = 'Hello'
  msg['From'] = sender
  msg['To'] = to
  s = smtplib.SMTP(server)
  s.sendmail(sender, [to], msg.as_string())
  s.quit()
```

I tried an example from the docs, which also failed.  http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/email-examples.html, the Send the contents of a directory as a MIME message example

Any suggestions?

Comment: To clarify, in 2.5.4, it sends without an error message, but replaces '€' with '?'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key is in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText):

```
class email.mime.text.MIMEText(_text, _subtype='plain', _charset='us-ascii')
```

> A subclass of MIMENonMultipart, the
>   MIMEText class is used to create MIME
>   objects of major type text. _text is
>   the string for the payload. _subtype
>   is the minor type and defaults to
>   plain. _charset is the character set
>   of the text and is passed as a
>   parameter to the MIMENonMultipart
>   constructor; it defaults to us-ascii.
>   No guessing or encoding is performed
>   on the text data.

So what you need is clearly, *not* `msg = MIMEText('€10')`, but rather:

```
msg = MIMEText('€10'.encode('utf-8'), _charset='utf-8')
```

While not all that clearly documented, [sendmail](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtplib#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) needs a byte-string, not a Unicode one (that's what the SMTP protocol specifies); look to what `msg.as_string()` looks like for each of the two ways of building it -- given the "no guessing or encoding", your way still has that euro character in there (and no way for sendmail to turn it into a bytestring), mine doesn't (and utf-8 is clearly specified throughout).

Comment: That sends without generating an error message. I sent to Thunderbird and gmail. Thunderbird only showed 10 as the text of the message.  Gmail showed the full €10.
Python sends as 'content-transfer-encoding: base64' while Thunderbird sends €10 as 'content-transfer-encoding: 8-bit' and gmail sends as 'multipart/alternative; boundary=...'   Any suggestions for generating a message that Thunderbird can interpret?

Comment: I'm no Thunderbird expert, but try other encodings such as `iso-8859-15`. Though any program these days that can't do utf-8 properly IS well worth throwing into the dustbin of history, mind!-)

Comment: The problem does not seem to be iso-8859-15 or utf-8, it seems to be content-transfer-encoding.  Everything else I checked uses 8-bit, while python uses base64.  Coercing the header to 8-bit doesn't help. Using quopri.encodestring() might work to get 8-bit encoding, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

`_charset` parameter of `MIMEText` defaults to `us-ascii` according to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText). Since `€` is not from us-ascii set it isn't working.

example in the docs that you've tried clearly states:

> For this example, assume that the text file contains only ASCII characters.

You could use [`.get_charset`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_charset) method on your message to investigate the charset, there is incidentally `.set_charset` as well.

Comment: As you say, the charset is us-ascii, which does not include €. Using set_charset on the msg does not fix the problem. The problem (I should have been more precise) is on the sendmail line - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 161: ordinal not in range(128) I read this to mean that I have to encode the text so that everything is in range(128), but I haven't been able to figure out how to.

Comment: I was looking at the 3rd example on the examples page, sending an entire directory. I tried sending a directory consisting of a single zip file using the example. This failed.