# smtplib exception when processing keystrokes with pynput

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, smtplib, pynput

**TL;DR:** 
found the bug, didnt solve it yet:
[Typing in english(left side), displayed in hebrew(right side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQDgC.jpg)

I have built a simple keylogger in **python 2.7** on my Ubuntu machine (VMware).
The exe file created supposed to show a picture and execute the keylogger at the background.
It is working on the host computer (the VMware host, **no python installed**) but not other computer I have(**no python as well**). It does show the picture but fails to send email using smtplib

for processing keystokes I used pynput like this:

```
keylistener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=proccess_keystrokes)
with keylistener:
sendGlobalVarLog()
keylistener.join()
```

and proccess_keystrokes is:

```
def process_key_press(self, key):
try:
    current_key = key.char
except AttributeError:
    current_key = '{0}'.format(key)
    if current_key == 'Key.space':
        current_key = " "
    else:
        if current_key == 'Key.enter':
            current_key = "\n"
        else:
            current_key = " " + current_key + " "
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    current_key = " bla "
self.append_to_log(current_key)
```

now it doesn't send anything on my windows machine, except from the first notification that the keylogger has started.

I tried to run in from pycharm as well, and after few second of running I get the following exception:

> File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 855, in sendmail
>       msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Anyone knows what do I do wrong? how can I parse the keystrokes correctly? I tried several manuals but couldn't find a solution.

Would appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: Does your code use a relative path to the image? (and is that the same path as where `--add-data` puts the image?)

Comment: Hey Niels, I have edited my post. This is the link to the image: file_name = sys._MEIPASS + "\image.jpg" from what i understand, if i write ;. at the end of the --add-data it saves the image on temp directory which sys._MEIPASS supposed to lead

Comment: Have you checked out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)?

Comment: I dont think it will help, the resource (Image) is loaded everytime. the script at the background is not working well (init is working but the listening to keystrokes is not)

Comment: @NielsHenkens I have found the bug, maybe you would know the answer now?

Comment: You have a typo in your except clause. it's not `exept` but `except`.

Comment: Thanks, it doesnt exist in code, no typos there

Comment: And the indentation of the code of your first version of `process_keystrokes` is correct in your code as well (not like it is here)?

Comment: Yes, assume no compilation bugs at all, sorry about that :)

Comment: The characters you get are unicode representation of hebrew letters. Could this be correct?

Comment: I am writing in english (I have verified) even thought I do have hebrew as a second language on my computer.
I swiched up my keystroke parser to something else (written above), and now, when running it on my windows i dont get any input. just a notification that the keylogger has started, and thats it. I tried running it from pycharm as well, there I get the following exception:

Comment: File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 855, in sendmail msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii') UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I would say that it somehow still looks like your input might be Hebrew (or some other non-ascii character). The `process_key_press` function will not raise a UnicodeEncodeError, so that except-clause won't do anything. Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987327/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-unicode-or-ascii) could be helpful in making a new check to determine if it's ascii or unicode? Or [check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329741/issue-with-smtplib-sending-mail-with-unicode-characters-in-python-3-1) for mailing with unicode.

Comment: I know what is the issue now. For some reason, current_key is processed as hebrew letter eventhough I press english letters (I just added print(current_key) and saw it, the console shows my types (english letters) and after each letter the print I added (hebrew letters) I have no idea why and how to deal with this. I cannot encode it since it will cause exception.

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding() shows utf-8

Comment: Added a link with a picture

Comment: Isn’t it just something simple like your keyboard language being Hebrew when you use the keylogger? Have you checked the language icon in the program bar when you use the keylogger?

Comment: Yes I did, see the picture I added as well, the keystrokes are in English. I assume it is something related to the default language of the OS, what do you think?