# How to send a pdf file to multiple emails using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, email-attachments

My aim for this program is to send multiple e-mail addresses a message along with a PDF file attached to the e-mail. How would I do that? I have two Traceback calls(Shown after the code). So far the code works when there is no attachments being sent but as I try to send an attachment everything seems to fall apart. Thanks

**EDIT:** I believe I have to use these two lines of code somewhere. 
message.attach(part)
text = message.as_string()

Although when I write them down it says Unresolved attribute reference 'attach' for class 'str'

```
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import pandas as pd
import smtplib, ssl

subject = "An email with attachment from Python"
sender_email = input("Enter your E-mail Address: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

email_list = pd.read_excel("D:\Learning Python\Mini_Projects\emailaddresses.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
# Read Excel Spreadsheet
names = email_list['Name']
receiver_email = email_list['Email']

message = """Subject: Training Program!  
Hi {names}, I hope you received this e-mail with the attachment"""
filename = "TrainingProgram.pdf"

with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())

encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header(
    "Content-Disposition",
    f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with  smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as server:
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    for i in range(len(receiver_email)):
        name = names[i]
        email = receiver_email[i]
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
    print("E-mails Sent!")



File "D:/Learning Python/Mini_Projects/main.py", line 117, in <module>
    server.sendmail(sender_email, [email], message)
  File "C:\Users\janss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 859, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4aa' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII encoding does not support emojis. Remove the  in the email body, and it should work. If you absolutely want to keep the emoji, you would have to use a `MIMEText` object, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329741/issue-with-smtplib-sending-mail-with-unicode-characters-in-python-3-1) for an example.

EDIT:
Why aren't you using the `name` and `email` variables in the for loop ?
The current code sends an email to an adress being a list, I wonder why it's not erroring there ...

```py
    for i in range(len(receiver_email)):
        name = names[i]
        email = receiver_email[i]
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Maybe you meant your for loop like the following ?

```py
    for email in receiver_email:
        server.sendmail(sender_email, email, message)
```

Additionally, your message will be sent as you coded it, instead of with the names filled in. For this, you need to put an f in front of the string. I think the `message` should be like this:

```py
message = f"""Subject: Training Program!
Hi {", ".join(names)}, I hope you received this e-mail with the attachment"""
```

EDIT2:

> `Unresolved attribute reference 'attach' for class 'str'`

This is because `str` has no method attach, only `email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart` has. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509278/14909980) on how to correctly send attachments.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the errors. My only issue now is that the attachment is not being sent a long with the e-mail. So I'm getting an empty e-mail with just the subject, body but no PDF files

Comment: @Johnlewis "I'm getting an empty e-mail with just the subject, body but no PDF files" - no wonder - you are loading the attachment PDF into your script, but never telling `smptlib` to send it along with your email ! And please re-read my post, I edited it because I found two more issues in your code which though aren't related to the PDF not being sent.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, much appreciated! I'll look more into it as I'm still a bit confused to as how I'll go about doing it.