# How to login me via smtplib with special characters? | Python3

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I want to login me a my Hotmail's account, with the module smtplib in python3. But I have a problem. The account's password has special characters. I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import smtplib
server=str(input("server: "))
email=str(input("email: "))
password="p@sswordñ!"
smtp=smtplib.SMTP(server,587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(email,password)
```

My error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

How Can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 smtplib send with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429147/python-3-smtplib-send-with-unicode-characters)

Comment: The passwords don't allow special characters of ASCII extend, only ASCII printables. https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/

Comment: What happens if you change this line (`password="p@sswordñ!"`) to: `password="p@sswordñ!".encode("utf-8")`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in smtplib. But you can do something like getting input as Unicode. Then the same string applies to another variable when it is used in the method.

```
server1=str(input("server: "))
email1=str(input("email: "))
password1 = input("Enter the Password: ")

def sendmail():
 server = server1
 email= email1
 password=password1
 smtp=smtplib.SMTP(server,587)
 smtp.ehlo()
 smtp.starttls()
 smtp.login(email,password)
```